# convert type error on byte array into Class Object

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, typeconverter

I am currently run into the problem that I can't convert my the byte array into class object.Moreover, I don't really know that if my serialize from class object into byte array.In addition, when I try to convert from bytes array to class object, Visual Studio gave me this error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ConsoleApplication15.exe
 Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication15.Player]' to type 'ConsoleApplication15.Player[]'.
```

Here is my Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String name = Console.ReadLine();
        int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Player Khanh = new Player(name, id);
        Khanh.testMethod(id);
        List<Player> ipTest = new List<Player>();
        ipTest.Add(Khanh);
        byte [] BytesList = ToByteList(ipTest);
        List<Player> PlayerList = ByteArrayToObject(BytesList).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(BytesList[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(PlayerList[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    public static byte[] ToByteList(List<Player> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    public static Player [] ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();

        memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Player[] obj = (Player[])binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

        return obj;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
   String Name;
    int id;
    public Player(String Name, int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;

    }
    public void testMethod(int n)
    {
        n++;
    }   
    public String getName ()
    {
        return Name;
    }

}
```

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong return type in the `ByteArrayToObject` method. You return a `List<Player>` but your current return type is `Player[]`.

Change this method to :

```
public static List<Player> ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();

    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var obj = (List<Player>)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

    return obj;
}
```